# Change text on hover with transition jQuery

Tags: jquery

Trying to achieve this: I have multiple headers, each with different text. When I hover over one header, the text changes accordingly (all text is different for each header) with a 'slide' animation.

I have gotten up to the point where the hover works fine, but when I try to add a simple transition, the functionality breaks.

HTML code:

```
<h1 id="mainText1">Header 1.</h1><span class="mainText1">Text 1.</span>
<h1 id="mainText2">Header 2.</h1><span class="mainText2">Text 2.</span>
<h1 id="mainText3">Header 3.</h1><span class="mainText3">Text 3.</span>
<h1 id="mainText4">Header 4.</h1><span class="mainText4">Text 4.</span>
```

The span is currently set to display: none; in CSS.

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("h1").hover(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var toShow = $("." + id);
        $(this).hide();
        $(toShow).show();
    }, function () {
        var id2 = $(this).attr('id');
        var toHide = $("." + id2);
        $(this).show();
        $(toHide).hide();
    });
});
```

It works fine if the 'slow' in line 7 is removed. I have also tried something like...

```
$(toShow).show().slideDown('slow');
```

.. but no luck as well. Am also looking for a cleaner solution rather than the posted one. My jQuery is too basic to figure out if this could be done better in another way. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I think I did not make myself clear, as I am seeing similar solutions. The h1 must disappear upon hover. I updated the JS code. This code is working as I intend it to be, but it does not contain the 'slide' animation. When I try putting the code for it to slide (like .slideDown('show'), it does not work as intended). Is there a way to do this?

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yvLs5/
Previous fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8rnuE/1/ (where I tried putting 'slow') and functionality breaks.

Comment: Try using `mouseover` instead of `hover` events

Comment: @blgt: jQuery's 'hover' is just a shortcut to defining mouseover and mouseleave in one call - under the hood, they're the same.

Comment: @Beejamin For what the question is described as, `mouseleave` appears unnecessary. Well, _was_ described anyway.

Comment: I don't know - all the versions show that the display needs to be restored on leave - is there a way of doing that with just mouseover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - the reason removing the 'slow' keyword in the call to `slideDown` works is it makes that transition instant. When you add the slow keyword, it makes the slide take time - however, javascript doesn't wait for the transition before moving on to the next line. So, the 'slideDown' is still in progress while the 'show' is occurring, which makes the layout jump all over the place.

The other issue you have is that your 'hover' event is only on 'h1' - which means that if the user hovers over the text that is revealed by the hover, the hover is canceled, which then hides the text... which pulls the h1 back up under the cursor, so the event fires again, and so on...

Here's a different solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jGDIt

I wouldn't use javascript for this - I would just use CSS. First, you'll need to make a change to the structure of your HTML, so that the h1 and the revealed text are siblings inside a containing element (I've used `<div class="toggle-section">`, but you might like to use a `<section>` or some other block element):

```
<div class="toggle-section">
  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
  <p class="main-text">Main text 1</p>
</div>
<div class="toggle-section">
  <h1>Heading 2</h1>
  <p class="main-text">Main text 2</p>
</div>
<div class="toggle-section">
  <h1>Heading 3</h1>
  <p class="main-text">Main text 3</p>
</div>
<div class="toggle-section">
  <h1>Heading 4</h1>
  <p class="main-text">Main text 4</p>
</div>
```

Then, set up your CSS so the hover is triggered on the container, like so:

```
.toggle-section .main-text {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-section:hover h1,
.toggle-section:focus h1 {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-section:hover .main-text,
.toggle-section:focus .main-text {
  display: block;
}
```

That's the basic show/hide behaviour, without requiring javascript. If you want transitions, you can do that too, so long as you know the height of 'main-text' in advance. If you do, change your CSS to:

```
.toggle-section h1,
.toggle-section .main-text {
  -moz-transition: height 400ms;
  -o-transition: height 400ms;
  -webkit-transition: height 400ms;
  transition: height 400ms;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 1.2em;
}
.toggle-section .main-text {
  height: 0;
}

.toggle-section:hover h1, .toggle-section:focus h1 {
  height: 0;
}
.toggle-section:hover .main-text, .toggle-section:focus .main-text {
  height: 1.2em;
}
```

Then, when you hover/focus the element, the height of main-text will expand to 1.2em over 400ms.

There are a few advantages to doing it this way:

- It works without javascript - that's especially handy if you're still
  beginning with javascript/jQuery: if you break something by accident,
  your toggles still work.
- It's faster: Your CSS will usually be ready before your Javascript on
  your pages.
- It's neater - it doesn't mix display stuff into your Javascript.

One thing to look out for with a set up like this: Hover doesn't work on phones or touch devices (either you're touching the screen or not). You should provide another option for those devices.

Comment: Great - css and html only solution - chuck it in a fiddle or codepen?

Comment: That's fixed - also, added the behaviour to hide the h1 on hover.

Comment: Dude, this is awesome! Thanks a lot. I never thought it was possible with CSS. Voting this as best answer. Thanks again :)

Comment: Also, thanks for reminding me about the limitations of hover. The text isn't all-important so it won't appear on mobile :)

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="topic">
  <h1 id="mainText1">Header 1.</h1>
  <span class="mainText1">Text 1.</span></div>
<div class="topic">
  <h1 id="mainText2">Header 2.</h1>
  <span class="mainText2">Text 1.</span></div>
<div class="topic">
  <h1 id="mainText3">Header 3.</h1>
  <span class="mainText3">Text 1.</span></div>
<div class="topic">
  <h1 id="mainText4">Header 4.</h1>
  <span class="mainText4">Text 1.</span></div>
```

**CSS**

```
span {display:none;}
h1{background:yellow;margin:0;}
```

**Script**

```
$('.topic').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.topic').find('span.'+$(this).find('h1').attr('id')).show();
    $(this).find('h1').hide();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('.topic').find('span.'+$(this).find('h1').attr('id')).hide();
    $(this).find('h1').show();
});
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8rnuE/6/)</kbd>

Comment: Nope! The header text which i'm hovering over must disappear/hide.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't hide the H1 it works

http://jsfiddle.net/j5J4F/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("h1").hover(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var toShow = $("." + id);
        $(toShow).show('slow');
    }, function () {
         var id2 = $(this).attr('id');
        var toHide = $("." + id2);
        $(toHide).hide();
    });
});
```

The browser was getting into a pickle, because on hovering over the H1 it then hid the h1, triggering the mouse-out event that then showed the H1 again and hid the span.

note - the `span` should really be replaced by a block level element such as a `p` to be semantically correct.

Comment: Then try putting two spans inside the h1. Get the code to hide the first span and show the second on hovering - so the h1 never loses focus. I also suggest adding the same transition to the hide as you do to the show. OR if you need different styling on each element, wrap them in a DIV and put the hover on that.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem comes cause you are hiding the element you hove over.
Here is a piece of code to hide the element.

```
<h1 id="mainText1">
    <span class="mainText1_main">Header 1.</span>
    <span class="mainText1">Text 1.</span>
</h1>

function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var toHide = $("." + id + "_main");
    var toShow = $("." + id);
    $(toHide).hide();
    $(toShow).show('slow');
}
```

Comment: You can style it then to make the text not look like an h1, or wrap everything on a div and then use the h1 and span (best one, actually). Just remember which element you are hovering over.